# Magento2: What is the difference between referenceContainer and reference?

Tags: magento2

I found some `xml` layout files that uses reference container and only reference. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<reference>` is from Magento 1 and is not included in Magento 2, so if you are seeing this it must be left over code from a Magento 1 conversion. This seems to get ignored in Magento 2.

For more info on Magento 1's `<reference>` read [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html).

And for info on Magento 2's `<referenceBlock>` and `<referenceContainer>` read [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref).